# Support for defaultProps is deprecated but still shown in formal documentation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I use my Component like this in react 18.2:

```
const Component = ({prop=true}) => (<div></div>)
```

I get this error message in console:

> Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a
> future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.

Yet the docs on https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#specifying-a-default-value-for-a-prop specifically give that way:

```
function Avatar({ person, size = 100 }) {}
```

What's the right way that console won't scream at me?

Comment: Are you using some form of transpiling that converts the default params to defaultProps? Is this from a third party component? The examples you have shown are default params, defaultProps is `const ComponentA = {}; ComponentA.defaultProps = { size: 100 };`.

Comment: Well yes and no, this is a component that I wrote that includes a bar chart inside. But the prop isn't related to that so I don't see the relation. https://www.tremor.so/docs/visualizations/bar-chart

Comment: It uses recharts, see [here](https://github.com/tremorlabs/tremor/blob/main/src/components/chart-elements/BarChart/BarChart.tsx)  and recharts has an [open issue](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/3615) about this which they will probably fix before it becomes an actual issue. TLDR it's a problem with recharts, if you want it fixed faster you're going to need to make some PRs on recharts and then tremor.